# Internet Explorer applying all stylesheets to webpage while printing, regardless of media type

Tags: css, internet-explorer, printing, media

I am experiencing a strange issue while trying to print in Internet Explorer. I have only tested with IE8.

My stylesheets with media="screen" are being applied even when printing. My page prints properly in Firefox/Chrome.

My head element:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Page title</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/reset.css" media="all" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/global.css" media="screen" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/site.css" media="screen" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="Stylesheet" href="/styles/jquery.css" media="screen" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/forms.css" media="screen" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/print.css" media="print" />

    <script src="/scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.8.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/scripts/modernizr-1.6.min.js"></script>
    <!--[if (gte IE 6)&(lte IE 8)]>
        <script src="/scripts/selectivizr-1.0.1.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <script src="/scripts/colorbox/jquery.colorbox-min.js"></script>
    <script src="/scripts/global.js"></script>
    <script src="/scripts/site.js"></script>
</head>
```

I have tried searching, and I have not been able to find any related issues. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your head element doesn't tell us much; it would be more useful to see an example of a CSS rule that's being incorrectly applied.

Comment: Using @import anywhere in your stylesheets?

Comment: Also: check what browser/document mode IE8 is running in. You can typically do that by hitting F12, then find it somewhere in the bottom pane that pops up.

Comment: I read somewhere about adding an ie-print.css within the conditional comment with media-type print and removing elements you do not want with !important. Could that work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Can you provide us a link?
This might be a probable solution.

Try switching your print stylesheets' rel value to `rel="alternate"`